# https://www.php.net/releases/?json return security check html page

Tags: json, gulp

I´m doing a gulp script. Inside it, I need to get the lastest releases php version dynamically.
I did this :

```
var php_index = 7;
gulp.task( 'init_php_version',  function( callback ) {
    return request("https://www.php.net/releases/?json&version=" + php_index, function(error, response, body) {
        console.dir( body );
        if (!error) {
            requires_php = body[php_index].version;
        }
    });
});
```

For some reason I received :

> ## Security Check
>
> Host Working
>
> ### What happened?
>
> You ran into a security check to verify the validity of your
> request.
>
> ### What can I do?
>
> #### If you are a visitor of this website:
>
> You must confirm that you are human.
>
> #### If you are the owner
> of this website:
>
> Please check your security settings.

How can I fixe this ?

Comment: You haven't shared the complete output. Is it because it doesn't add any relevant detail as about why the check failed, or because you haven't had a look inside?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I modify the output. The problem that output is higher than 30 000 characters :/

Comment: I think the message pretty much says it all. Either the service terms do not allow bots or you're exceeding their requests limit.